# How to connect an ActiveRecord model to another model using two attributes with belongs_to

Tags: activerecord, foreign-keys, belongs-to

Please I would like some help to solve the problem below.

I'm trying to connect two activerecord models, one of the models (Job) has two attributes, hiring_company_id and advertising_company_id, which reference the other model (CompanyBase). But, I'm getting an sql error, no such table: main.hiring_companies:, when saving the Job model.

I wrote the code this way, I omitted some attributes to be more concise:

Job Model:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail on: [:update, :destroy]
  belongs_to :job_type, inverse_of: :jobs
  belongs_to :advertising_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', foreign_key: :advertising_company_id, inverse_of: :jobs
  belongs_to :hiring_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', foreign_key: :hiring_company_id, inverse_of: :jobs
  validates :hide_advertising_company, inclusion: { in: [true, false], message: :must_be_true_or_false }, if: lambda { advertising_company.present? }
end
```

ActiveRecord migration for the Job model:

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.belongs_to :job_type, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :advertising_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', foreign_key: :advertising_company_id
      t.belongs_to :hiring_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', foreign_key: :hiring_company_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

CompanyBase model:

```
class CompanyBase < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail on: [:update, :destroy]
  has_many :jobs, foreign_key: :advertising_company_id, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :company_base
  has_many :jobs, foreign_key: :hiring_company_id, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :company_base
end
```

When I create the Job object and I try to save it I get the following sql error, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.hiring_companies. But I don't get the same error for the advertising_company attribute, and the code is the same. What I am doing wrong ?

```
irb(main):018:0> jb.save!
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("country_w_id", "job_type_id", "advertising_company_id", "hiring_company_id", "position", "handicapped_only", "hide_advertising_company", "hide_hiring_company", "hide_salary", "description", "requisites", "salary_from", "salary_to", "work_time", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["country_w_id", 1], ["job_type_id", 1], ["advertising_company_id", 1], ["hiring_company_id", 1], ["position", "Gerente"], ["handicapped_only", "f"], ["hide_advertising_company", "f"], ["hide_hiring_company", "f"], ["hide_salary", "f"], ["description", "descrição"], ["requisites", "requisitos"], ["salary_from", 10], ["salary_to", 100], ["work_time", "full"], ["created_at", "2017-08-06 19:03:18.295519"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-06 19:03:18.295519"]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.hiring_companies: INSERT INTO "jobs" ("country_w_id", "job_type_id", "advertising_company_id", "hiring_company_id", "position", "handicapped_only", "hide_advertising_company", "hide_hiring_company", "hide_salary", "description", "requisites", "salary_from", "salary_to", "work_time", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        from (irb):18
i
```

Thanks,

Jose Fernando

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem and I am posting the answer here to people with similar issue.
The issue was caused by a wrong relation name. The correct way is:

Job model:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail on: [:update, :destroy]
  belongs_to :job_type, inverse_of: :jobs
  belongs_to :advertising_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', inverse_of: :jobs
  belongs_to :hiring_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', inverse_of: :jobs
  validates :hide_advertising_company, inclusion: { in: [true, false], message: :must_be_true_or_false }, if: lambda { advertising_company.present? }
end
```

ActiveRecord migration for the Job model:

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.belongs_to :job_type, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :advertising_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', index: true
      t.belongs_to :hiring_company, class_name: 'CompanyBase', index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

CompanyBase model:

```
class CompanyBase < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail on: [:update, :destroy]
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :advertising_company
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :hiring_company
end
```

Best regards,

Jose Fernando